# Lexmark X7675 printer driver needed

Tags: drivers, printing, lexmark

Does anyone have a copy of the Lexmark Printer X7675 driver for Ubuntu 13.04 or Debian?

Lexmark no longer supports this printer apparently. I visit a site that gave a link that no longer works for a download.

If any has this file or an equivalent, please make it available somehow.

Thanks, Daniel

File needed:  lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz   or one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you can [download](http://ubuntuone.com/68YvYqx10WczcdxsUWKMTE) the driver.  Make sure that you have the 32bit version of Ubuntu, because this a 32bit driver only.

Once downloaded follow the following:

A. RUNNING THE GUI INSTALLER SCRIPT IN THE TERMINAL

Open up terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
Extract the zip file
Use the following command to install the driver
#./lexmark-inkjet-[xx]-driver-[x.x.x]..i386.deb.sh
Follow the instruction in the installation screen.
```

B. RUNNING THE GUI INSTALLER SCRIPT

```
Do not attach the printer via USB to the Linux machine.
Extract the zip file.
lexmark-inkjet-[xx]-driver-[x.x.x].i386.deb.sh
Run the installer script file by double-clicking on the file icon and then click the "Run in Terminal" button or run the script file via command-line.
Follow the instructions in the installer screen.
```

<sup>Installation instructions Source:Lexmark</sup>