# lexmark x7675 printer driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, dpkg, lexmark

I'd like to leave windows 10 but I haven't found a way to install the 32bit driver (lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz or lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.zip) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Steps (found in other forums for previous versions of Ubuntu): 
sudo ./lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh --noexec --target ./lexmark
cd lexmark/
sudo tar xvf instarchive_all --lzma
sudo dpkg -i --force-all lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb

```
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb (--install):
 Parsen der Datei Â»/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/controlÂ«, nahe Zeile 9 Paket Â»lexmark-08z-series-driver:i386Â«:
 Leerzeile im Wert des Feldnamen Â»DescriptionÂ«
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
kon@SERAPH:~/Temp/lexmark$

-> empty row in value of fieldname "Description" ...l
```

Any ideas other than keep using Windows?

Thanks and best regards ...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/340297/589808